# How to wait until a variable is set in order to fetch from API? (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an e-commerce site on React and using Firebase as back-end.
I want to store users' carts on the database, but I'm having trouble fetching the cart on reload, since I need to wait until the object AuthUser (provided by firebase) is ready in order to identify said user and fetch its cart from the API

```
if(authUser){fetch(
  `https://nameofmyapp.firebaseio.com/carts/${authUser.uid}.json`
)
  .then((response) => response.json()).then((cart) => {
    setCart(cart))
```

Using this inside useEffect without dependencies didn't work, since it seems to run before AuthUser is set

I tried using promises, but I don't understand it very well

```
    function ensureAuthUserIsSet() {
    return new Promise(waitForAuthUser);

    function waitForAuthUser(resolve) {
        if (authUser)
            resolve(authUser);
    }
}
 
ensureAuthUserIsSet().then(function(){
    console.log("it's set", authUser)})
```

Using this promise detects when AuthUser is set, but if I leave it outside useEffect, it runs many times (I don't want to make multiple API calls unnecesarily), and if I insert it into the useEffect without dependencies it never detects AuthUser at all

I don't know if this is of help, but this is the useEffect responsible for setting authUser (I took it from a tutorial):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setAuthUser(user);
    } else {
      setAuthUser(null);
    }
  });
  return () => {
    listen();
  };
}, []);
```

What can I do? Thank you

Comment: "*Using this inside useEffect without dependencies didn't work*" so why don't you use a dependency on the `authUser` in the `useEffect` dependencies list?

Comment: The very first `if(authUser) fetch..` should not run before AuthUser is set. In your tutorial snippet, you set AuthUser to true if  there is any user object - could that might be a problem?

Comment: Gabriele's suggestion worked like a charm, I included authUser in the dependencies list and kept the if(authUser) at the start so the code only runs when authUser is effectively set and not on component mount, thank you!